# Place imageview next to textview - (image view get repeated) CHAT UI

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, user-interface

I would like to place imageview next to textview.

Here is my XML:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leftText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/maven_pro_black"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:text="Hello this is me!!"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#212121"
        />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/leftText"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:src="@drawable/user_2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/leftText"/>

     </RelativeLayout>

   <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/rightText"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:src="@drawable/user_1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rightText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner1"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/maven_pro_black"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="Hi!! How are you!!"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how it looks like in real world:

[image: In the picture below you can see the repeated images]

p.s. I tried & and not working:

android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/BLABLA"
and even

android:drawableLeft="@drawable/your_image_name"

it was good try but not what I want.  HOW CAN I DISABLE THIS REPATABLE IMAGES AS YOU SEE IN SCREENSHOT? Thanks.

EDIT added my massage activity:

```html
adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatMessage, chat_rec>(ChatMessage.class,R.layout.msglist,chat_rec.class,ref.child("chat")) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(chat_rec viewHolder, ChatMessage model, int position) {

                if (model.getMsgUser().equals("user")) {

                    viewHolder.rightText.setText(model.getMsgText());
                    
                    viewHolder.rightText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewHolder.leftText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
                else {
                    viewHolder.leftText.setText(model.getMsgText());

                    viewHolder.rightText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    viewHolder.leftText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: As I understand it, each View contains both the left and the right side messages? Why? Without the corresponding code, I can't really say what's wrong. Also on a sidenote, don't use RelativeLayouts for this, at the very least, switch to LinearLayout or better yet, use compound drawables in TextView

Comment: The problem is that images appear where is NO chat bubble in the image above that I posted, I rounded with the red circle images that not suppose to appear. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: I want bubble chat and image only. But somehow below the bubble chat always appear image too where is NO chat at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I made the workaround and it is working somehow. 
I added this to my layout --> textview -->

```
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user_1"
        android:drawablePadding="6dp"
        android:paddingLeft="30dip"
        android:paddingRight="26dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:gravity="center"
```

android:drawablePadding="6dp" and android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user_1" make the solution somehow acceptable. I hope this will be too someone useful. Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your RelativeLayout to LinearLayout like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leftText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/maven_pro_black"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:text="Hello this is me!!"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#212121"
        />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/leftText"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:src="@drawable/user_2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/leftText"/>

     </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/rightText"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:src="@drawable/user_1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rightText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner1"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/maven_pro_black"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="Hi!! How are you!!"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it isn't solve anything. Only now these pictures are in the middle. I don't want them except next to bubble chat.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leftText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/maven_pro_black"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:text="Hello this is me!!"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#212121"
        />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/leftText"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:src="@drawable/user_2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/leftText"/>

     </RelativeLayout>

   <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:src="@drawable/user_1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rightText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner1"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/maven_pro_black"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="Hi!! How are you!!"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

There is no attribute orientation for a RelativeLayout. And I've just moved your attribute alignParent from TextView to RelativeLayout (parent of TextView)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it isn't solve anything. Only now these pictures are now one LEFT and one RIGHT. I don't want them except next to bubble chat.

Comment: I think it's not a problem of layout here... If you want to put chat and bubble (one right, one left), the layout is good. But, if you want to disappear bubble where chat line is empty, you need to add in your code findViewById(R.id.layout1).setVisibility(View.GONE) for example

Comment: I have code like this: viewHolder.rightText.setText(model.getMsgText());

                    viewHolder.rightText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewHolder.leftText.setVisibility(View.GONE);                    
                }
                else {
                    viewHolder.leftText.setText(model.getMsgText());

                    viewHolder.rightText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    viewHolder.leftText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   
                }

Comment: And I added viewHolder.rightImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); and so on... But how to get viewHolder from imageView? Like this for the TEXT: viewHolder.rightText.setText(model.getMsgText());    ??

Comment: It's difficult for me to answer you with only your layout. I don't know how you manage this list. But for me, you show and/or hide the relativelayout which contains text and image

Comment: elgringo, I added my massage activity snippet (look up I added edit to my first post). You can see cleary that I used for my text massage setVisibility(View.GONE);    But the question is how can I do this for Images?

Comment: I suppose that chat_rec class contains a pointer on your textview, just add a pointer on your imageview. But I think it's better to have a pointer on your relativelayout (identifier in your code : layout1 / relativeLayout)

Comment: Yes, you are right, I added a pointer in chat_rec class but now I must somehow set view image view GONE  and viewHolder.leftImage.setVisibility(View.GONE); don't work! (because is the imageView and not textView and I must somehow add viewHolder.leftImage.set. xxxxxx I don't know what)